# Auto size of table view cell does not appear to work in a standard UIViewController class

Tags: ios, swift, autosize, uitableview

I have created a test project in order to verify this problem.  In the project storyboard I have two scenes.  One scene is based on the initial `ViewController` that was added to the single view application when the project was created.  The second scene was created by dragging a `UITableViewController` onto the storyboard.

In both scenes, I believe I have configured the prototype cell so it should auto size.  When I set the initial `ViewController` to the one based on the UIViewController, the `UITableViewCell` do not show / size correctly.  (See below)

[image: Resize did not work]

However, when I set the initial `ViewController` to the one based on the `UITableViewController`, everything works fine.  (see below)

[image: resize works]

The code / project is very simple and I am hoping someone has seen this and can tell me why the auto size for the `UITableViewCell` is not working correctly when the class is based on `UIViewController` verses a `UITableViewController`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  It appears I cannot upload the project here so I will try to get it uploaded to another location and update the question with a link.

To answer standard questions

1. Both prototype cells have two `UILabel` in them

   2. The first `UILabel` has left, top, right and bottom constraints specified.
   3. The second `UILabel` has left, right and bottom constraints specified.
   4. Both classes set the estimatedRowHeight to a number and the rowHeight to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
   5. All `UILabel` have their lines property set to 0
   6. The first `UILabel` in both scenes has its Line Breaks set to Word Wrap
   7. The second `UILabel` in both scenes has its Line Breaks set to Truncate Tail.

Below is a screen shot of the scene in interface builder.  Left is based in `UIViewController`, right is based on `UITableViewController`

[image]

Here is a link to the code I hope: [Sample Project](https://github.com/gceaser/AutoSizeTableViewCell)

Comment: Can you share the simple project code via Github? It's possible to use a UITableView with a UIViewController and get Automatic dimensions to work.

Comment: You need top, left, and right constraints for the first label, and left, bottom and right for the second one. And vertical distance constraint between them. Is that how you set them up?

Comment: Check numberOfLines property of UILabels in both the cells. It should be set to 0.

Comment: All I answered these questions in my question though the list did not come out clear.  All of the constraints and number of lines are set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the "silver bullet" that seems to resolve a great number of challenges regarding auto layout of prototype cells.

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath function I added the following line of code right before I return the cell:

```
lobj_NearbyLocationEntry!.layoutIfNeeded()
```

(lobj_NearbyLocationEntry is the name of my cell variable I am returning.)

When I do this, the auto layout for my table works fine.  On a side note, I found a defect in the code that uses the UITableViewController also.  Once the data loads and it all looks good, if you scroll down and then scroll back up, you will see a couple of the cells are now not laid out correctly.  Putting this line of code in that view controller's code also resolved that layout problem.

I hope this helps many people who are sitting there trying to figure out why their app is not auto laying out a tableView cell correctly. :)

Answer (score 0):

For Me It Works

1. Give upper `UILabel` (right,top,left) constraints
2. Give lower `UILabel` (right,top,left,bottom) constraints

**In Custom `UITableViewcell`**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    up.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping // Label outlet
    down.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping // Label outlet
    up.numberOfLines = 0
    down.numberOfLines = 0
    // Initialization code
}
```

**EDIT**

**In`UITableViewController`**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**In `UIViewController`**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: This example cannot be from a UIViewController example as it has the override func tableView and the override is only present when it is using the UITableViewController. :)  I am working on getting the exact code uploaded.

Comment: The sample code has been uploaded to GitHub.  Can anyone tell me how to get this to work correctly?

Comment: Remove: `myTable.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0 , myTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` from `ViewController` and do same in `TableViewController`. follow the steps mention in answer. I have tested and it works.